# How to use jQuery hasClass when the selector is a JS variable

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

I am trying to use jQuery's `hasClass` function. It doesn't seem to work when I use it like this. I would appreciate it if anyone can work out how to use hasClass in this situation.

The error I am getting is

```
numValueElement.hasClass is not a function
if($(numValueElement.hasClass("tag")))
```

The key line throwing this error is this one `if($(numValueElement.hasClass("tag")))`

```
$(".numberValue").click
    (
        function ()
        {
            var numValueElement = this;
            var propertyId = numValueElement.id;
            $(".numberBounds").filter("#"+propertyId).toggle();
            if($(numValueElement.hasClass("tag")))
            {
            }

        }
    );
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.hasClass()` is a jQuery object method, not something attached to the element itself.

You need to know the difference between a jQuery object wrapped element, and a plain DOM element.

What you want is:

```
$(numValueElement).hasClass("class-name")
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
if( $(yourVariable).hasClass("someClass") ) {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if($(numValueElement).hasClass("tag"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it in this way
$(numValueElement).hasClass("tag")

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#'+this.id).hasClass('class-name')){

}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.